# Move files from subfolders to another folder

Tags: python

I want to move all the files from multiple subdirectories to another folder in the same directory as the parent folder but get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw/Emmit_Smith/Emmit_Smith_0001.jpg' -> '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/negatives/Emmit_Smith_0001.jpg'
```

this is my code:

```
for directory in os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw'):
  for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw', directory)):
    path = os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw', directory, file)
    new_path = os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/negatives', file)
    os.replace(path, new_path)
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: is  /content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw/Emmit_Smith/Emmit_Smith_0001.jpg a link?

Comment: yes it is a file in one of the subfolders (sorry took a while to find it)

Comment: Does the directory `/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/negatives` exist?

Comment: @Cuartero yes it exists in and they both sit in FaceRec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

src_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dev/FaceRec/lfw'
dest_path = src_path.replace('lfw', 'negatives')
flist = glob.glob(os.path.join(src_path, '*/*'))
for fname in flist:
    shutil.move(fname, fname.replace(os.path.dirname(fname), dest_path))
```

Why this is better:

1. The `glob` functions helps to avoid one for loop and also prevents from repeatedly joining the paths together
2. `shutil.move`creates the destination directory for you if it does not exist. Also it can handle symlinks.
3. By putting the paths in variables we can minimize copy past errors

Comment: Thanks for the input but I did manage it some other way. Your answer seems to be working for this problem too though.